Developing an Azure DevOps Extension with Backend
I’m working on an Azure DevOps extension and have a couple of questions:

I want to use a backend for handling big data tasks in my extension. Are there any tips or docs for using a backend with Azure DevOps extensions?
I can access Azure API services by sending the token from getAccessToken on the frontend SDK to the backend. But what happens if the token expires during long processes? Is there a way to get a new token?
Is there any documentation available for best practices regarding using a backend for Azure DevOps extensions?

Is there any documentation available for best practices regarding using a backend for Azure DevOps extensions?

I didn't find an official documentation on using a backend for Azure DevOps extensions. How would you like to use a backend for handling big data tasks? I only found this document about the Data storage of Azure DevOps extensions. Azure DevOps extensions can store user preferences and complex data structures directly on Microsoft-provided infrastructure.
